# What's disconnecting my Websocket connection? (cloudflare, apache's mod_proxy)

Tags: apache, websocket, cloudflare, mod-proxy

All my websocket connections arrive over the http(s) port and are proxied to the backend WS server:

```
[client]----[cloudflare]----[Apache 2.4 mod_proxy_wstunnel]----[websocket server]
```

Once a client connects to my WS server, if no data goes through the socket, the connection is always cut off after exactly 100 seconds.

In the dev environment, with the same client, also using `mod_proxy_wstunnel`, and the same WS server, this limitation does not occur

If the WS server sends a ping every 60 seconds, the connection is not cut off.

I'd like to know whether anyone has seen documentation about Cloudflare disconnecting quiet WS connections, and whether `mod_proxy` as it is setup on the server could be the cause.  I'm not sure how to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Every web server / proxy **should** account for "half-closed" sockets and either implement a ping or timeout mechanism (not everyone does this)... Heroku would have disconnected you after ~55 seconds or so. Implementing a ping when using Websockets is advised (usually implemented by the server, closing the socket on error).

Comment: @Myst I'm new not only to websockets, but to networking in general. So what I observed is nothing unusual? I thought websockets were designed to remain open until one end disconnects.

Comment: it's very usual. It's expected behavior... I suspect the timeout of 100 seconds could be actually considered long.

Comment: @Myst sounds like I'll need to ping.  Do you have an informed opinion about whether the clients should be pinging the server or the other way around? I'm thinking `server-->client`, this way the server can better manage the process (pings will occur at predictable intervals, and will all be done together, in an array loop)

Comment: Most clients are browsers that can't control a protocol compliant `ping` and end up sending empty data or custom ping events. Server side is definitely the way to go. Look into the protocol's ping specification and it will make life a little easier for you (browsers will automatically reply with a pong). I would recommend the interval to be adjustable so that different hosting systems could be easily employed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A support tech confirmed to me via email that Cloudflare automatically disconnects websocket connections that remain dormant for 100 seconds.

Comment: How do you keep them open? Heartbeat / pings?

Comment: How do you keep them open? Does Heartbeat / pings work?

Comment: I'm doing reconnect.

    function connect() { 
        const ws = new WebSocket('wss://...');
        ws.onclose = () => setTimeout(connect, 1000);
        ws.onerror = () => setTimeout(connect, 1000);
    }

Comment: @Jack Yes! Sending a heartbeat/ping over the websocket connection (I do it once every 90 seconds) does indeed keep the connection open. (I know because I just implemented that as a fix for this issue myself)

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue. I changed "proxied" mode to DNS only and bought my own certificate from GoDaddy. After that not facing that issue. Detailed discussion is present here: https://techxperiment.blogspot.com/2020/06/aws-ec2-tomcat-jsr-356-secure.html

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare has 100 seconds timeout.
Only enterprise users of Cloudflare can change this setting.

So the solution is to have some keep-alive to re-open to connection. Alternatively, a much better solution would be not to use CloudFlare at all. It will give you much more flexibility, and you won't have to depend on external third party.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest that send pings to the connection to avoid disconnecting.  Sending pings to the WebSocket connection can help to prevent disconnections.